# Is there any way to set different "y" limits to a ggplot graph which contains a "facet_wrap()"?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with a dataset and I want to set different limits for "y" axis, depending on the "Level" which the graph will be faceted by.
I tried to create a dataframe containing column-list that contains, in each row, a vector of length 2 that represents my maximum and inferior limit and a column with "Level" data (the column which is being used to `facet_wrap()`, then I tried to set the limits in this part of my code:
`lims(data = lim_df_agg_sub, aes(y = Limites_y, x = c(NA, NA)))` 
Where:

- lim_df_agg_sub is the dataframe containing the limits and levels;
- Limites_y is the column list containing a vector of length 2 with maximum and minimum limit.

The error I got from Rstudio is `Error: All arguments must be named`, adn when I run `rlang::last_error()`, it shows me this message:

```
All arguments must be named
Backtrace:
1. ggplot2::lims(...)
```

Is there any way to do what I want?

Comment: @starja thanks for aswering! The answer that you provided helped me to free scales when I have a faceted graph, thanks for this by the way. But what I want to do is to set minimum and maximum values for "y" axis, to facet them. I'll answer in 2 parts, otherwise I can't publish my answer.

Comment: @starja , for exemple, it's not always my graph will be faceted by Levels, but when it happens I would like to be able to use some dataframe I created with the limits for "y" axis and the levels of facetting so I can pass this data frame like this, for exemple (I know it won't work, I already tried, rs)  `lims(data  = df, aes(y = lim_y))`. Then, with `facet_wrap()`, I could facet the these limits according to the column "Level" I have in the dataframe "df". OBS: The problem is not with the conditional, to facet or not, but with the limits I want to set, everything else is working fine!